# The best way to work with Docker and Azure DevOps multStage

Tags: azure, docker, azure-devops

I created a yml file to build and deploy my app to Azure, but I'm thinking the best way to work with Azure Multstage and Docker ? Do I need to Create a image to each environment like DSV, HML or PRD? or Can I build a image and replace to publish in others environments?

Answer (score 0):

- No, you have to create custom images for specific environments
- A better way would be to use azure Kubernetes services thus you don't
  have to manage anything or create custom images.
- This can done using `Devops starter` which will help in deploying docker images to azure

Refer the following [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops-project/azure-devops-project-aks) on AKS.